# Grails Hibernate Insert instead of update table

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails

In my current update function's save part (I tried flush: true and insert:true) there will be executed an insert everytime I try.

The column I want to update is a Primary Key, but in the mysql-database I have ON UPDATE CASCADE in all foreign key uses.

Is there anything else I have to pay attention in grails or elsewhere?

UPDATE:
I have the following tables:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Station` (
  `Name` CHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `Location_Designation` CHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Name`, `Location_Designation`) ,
  INDEX `fk_Station_Location1_idx` (`Location_Designation` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Station_Location_LocatedIn`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Location_Designation` )
    REFERENCES `Location` (`Designation` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Location` (
  `Designation` CHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Designation`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

my grails:

```
stationInstance.properties = params
//Station = "S1", Location="test"

if (!stationInstance.save(flush: true)) { // }
```

UPDATE 2:
This ist what my hibernate does at update-command:

```
Hibernate: select station_.name, station_.Location_Designation as Location2_2_ from station station_ where station_.name=?
Hibernate: insert into station (Location_Designation, name) values (?, ?)
```

Comment: Show samples you have tried with.

Comment: @dmahapatro I updated the question with the tables. Thanks for helping me (again)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are updating a primary key you probably can't get away with a save here.  You'll probably need to use HQL with executeUpdate like this:

```
Station.executeUpdate("update Station s set s.name=? where s.name=?", name2, name1)
```

Comment: Is this common solving of this 'problem' or are there methods to avoid my case by eg defining the domain in a more accurate way?
Anyway, this helped. Thanks!

Comment: @malte: The general rule is not to use a data field as a primary key but rather an auto-generated field or something similar.  You don't want to be updating your primary key a lot particularly as it could be a foreign key used in a multitude of other places.  Also, Grails seems to work better when there's only one field it can use as an id.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I have already been pushed in that direction. But what if it is a database driven development and the 'database engineers' did that stuff without noticing me moaning? Then the above solution is what I **have** to implement, correct? :)